# How to send null character through python webservice

Tags: python, xml, web-services, suds

I have a need to send a string which contains null character (`\0`) in python to server through webservice. But I always got string cut off on server side. For example, I sent `20167139-ABCDo82\0VBh|D` but only received `20167139-ABCDo82`.

Is that because the webservice see `\0` as special and dump it and followings? If yes, how I can fix it?

Comment: Is the server something you have access to? If not, and it drops everything after the null character, then you might not be able to do anything about it.

Comment: @skyler yes I do have access to the server. And what to do?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question. I just wanted to make sure that you had access to the code in question because otherwise the problem would not be on your end and would not be resolvable.